# Table does not allow math mode and alignment problem

Tags: tables, math-mode, formatting, align

I am in the process of a writing a table and have run into two problems. My first problem is that I cannot type mathematical expressions in the table. I am unsure of how to adjust my code to enable math mode. My second problem is that I cannot vertically align the columns (although the second column is aligned as desired).

A MWE example is

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%%% TABLE %%%
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%%% DASHED LINES IN TABLE %%%
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{SSSSSSSS} \toprule
    \textbf{Example} & \textbf{Example} & \textbf{Example} & \textbf{Example}  \\ \midrule
    $D_{D}$  & \text{This is an example of a rather long sentence} & 2 & 3 \\ \hdashline
    1  & \text{This is an example of a rather long sentence} & 2 & 3 \\ \hdashline
    1  & \text{This is an example of a rather long sentence} & 2 & 3 \\ \hdashline
    1  & \text{This is a short sentence} & 2 & 3  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The output of the MWE is illustrated below

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

(red lines indicate page alyout)

- you define 7columns but use only 4
- text in `S` columns had to be enclosed by curly braces
- the second column contains only text, so here is better to employ non-`S` column type, for example `l` or in the case of really  long text, which can cause that table spill out of text border, should be automatically broken into two or more lines by use of the `p{<with>}` or `X` (actually `L` derived from `X`) column types

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}%{amsfonts}
%%% TABLE %%%
\usepackage{ragged2e}    % <--- new
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%%% DASHED LINES IN TABLE %%%
%\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \sisetup{table-format=1} % you need accommodate to used (decimal) numbers
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} SL SS @{}} 
    \toprule
{\textbf{Example}}  
    &   \textbf{Example} 
                &   {\textbf{Example}}
                    &   {\textbf{Example}}              \\
    \midrule
{$D_{D}$}           &   This is an example of a rather long sentence 
                        & 2 & 3                         \\ \hdashline
    1  &  This is an example of a rather very long sentence in two lines
                        & 2 & 3                         \\ \hdashline
    1  &  This is an example of a rather long sentence
                        & 2 & 3                         \\ \hdashline
    1  &  This is a short sentence
                        & 2 & 3                         \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

*Note*:
I would not use dashed horizontal lines. Instead them  you may insert some vertical space, for example by use of the `\addlinespace` defined in the `booktabs` package

**Addendum:**
In the case, that you like to have all cells content just in one line and left aligned, than you need to use `l` columns types, which will as you can see from result of such a code, quite ugly and spilling out of text area:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}%{amsfonts}
%%% TABLE %%%
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
%%% DASHED LINES IN TABLE %%%
%\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\setlength\dashlinedash{0.2pt}
\setlength\dashlinegap{1.5pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.3pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{ll ll} 
    \toprule
{\textbf{Example}}  
    &   \textbf{Example} 
                &   {\textbf{Example}}
                    &   {\textbf{Example}}              \\
    \midrule
{$D_{D}$}           &   This is an example of a rather long sentence 
                        & 2 & 3                         \\ \hdashline
    1  &  This is an example of a rather very long sentence in two lines
                        & 2 & 3                         \\ \hdashline
    1  &  This is an example of a rather long sentence
                        & 2 & 3                         \\ \hdashline
    1  &  This is a short sentence
                        & 2 & 3                         \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page alyout)

Comment: Is it possible to align each column to the left (just like column two in your figure)? Also, does the text in column two have to be over two lines (e.g. could "This is an example of a rather long sentence" be on the one line)?

Comment: @Bell, you can have all lines of `l` types (aligned to the lest), but in your MWE you use `S` columns, which align numbers at decimal point. Using only one line text your table (depending of text) can spill out of text area. Sorry, about this your question is not clear. Please edit it and populate your table with more realistic (dummy) text and numbers.

Comment: @I think  you have solved my problem :) I appreciate your help!

Comment: On a side note, in response to your note, do you think the dashed lines are unprofessional? The table is for a dissertation (for some context).

Comment: @Bell, yes, that is my opinion. See https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/. If my answer solve your problem, you may consider to accept it :-)